# Setting an email to delete automatically after a time period

Tags: email

I am looking to send emails that will delete after a given amount of time at their destination, giving them only a certain amount of time to respond.  I will be sending these emails to people who have different email clients, so a client side solution seems impossible.  Is there any sort of way to do this?

Comment: If people are clicking on a link just expire the link rather than attempting self-destructing e-mails.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no possibility of doing so. You can only make the content somehow expire by for example:

- Providing some link, that won't be avaliable after the period of time
- Embedding message in form of html, which simply displays image from your webserver and after this period - change the image to something saying "time is up"

Comment: +1 Basically, unless you're hosting it online, you can't delete it.